# Chrome CSS Linear Gradient - applying a 1 pixel block disappears but visible on zoom

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am trying to apply 4 white 1 pixels blocks in a linear gradient. Chrome is the only browser that seems to have issues rendering the white blocks. But if I zoom in I see them.

https://codepen.io/smks/pen/jOEEveL

```css
    .bar {
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 8px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(
          to right,
          #e91e63,
          #f44336 40%,
    
          white 40%,
          white calc(40% + 1px),
    
          #f44336 calc(40% + 1px),
          #fcb321 50%,
    
          white 50%,
          white calc(50% + 1px),
    
          #fcb321 calc(50% + 1px),
          #2cd664 60%,
    
          white 60%,
          white calc(60% + 1px),
    
          #2cd664 calc(60% + 1px),
          #2fb153 70%,
    
          white 70%,
          white calc(70% + 1px),
    
          #2fb153 calc(70% + 1px),
          #2fb153 100%
        );
    }
```

```html
 <div class="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple background instead

```css
.bar {
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
     transparent 0 calc(25% - 1px),
     white calc(25% - 1px) 25%) /* 25% to draw only 4 lines (100/25 = 4)*/
     center/ /*The second line will be on the center*/
     40% 100% /* 40% the width since we need 4 lines spaced by 10%*/
     no-repeat,
    /* Main background */
    linear-gradient(
     to right, 
     #e91e63, 
     #f44336 40%, 
     #fcb321 50%, 
     #2cd664 60%, 
     #2fb153 70%, 
     #2fb153 100%);
}

.old-bar {
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 8px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      #e91e63,
      #f44336 40%,

      white 40%,
      white calc(40% + 2px),

      #f44336 calc(40% + 2px),
      #fcb321 50%,

      white 50%,
      white calc(50% + 3px),

      #fcb321 calc(50% + 3px),
      #2cd664 60%,

      white 60%,
      white calc(60% + 2px),

      #2cd664 calc(60% + 2px),
      #2fb153 70%,

      white 70%,
      white calc(70% + 2px),

      #2fb153 calc(70% + 2px),
      #2fb153 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>

The old bar with bigger white lines to compare:
<div class="old-bar"></div>
```